# Synching validations between front-end and back-end projects

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, microservices, software-design

What do you do for synching validations between front-end and back-end teams in `laravel`?

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54412673/how-to-sync-front-end-and-back-end-validation) but I would like to know about `laravel`.

I have also seen [laravel js validation package](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation) but the problem is that front-end and back-end projects are not the same. The front-end project has been written in `vue.js`.

As a second question, what about the case that my validations exist in the database instead of the `formRequest`? e.g., I have an `API` to show items. These items have several regex validations. It is not secure to send them along with items. What should I do?

Comment: If you want help with code, you need to post the code you want help with. If you want help with a general idea of how to do something, I think you've come to the wrong place :p

Comment: @Bravo I would like a general idea. I added another tags.

Answer (score 0):

Is you are using Veu.js in laravel Project? and its session bases?

Comment: No, the vue.js project is separated from the laravel project.